# Is supportedInterfaceOrientations settings working properly in simulator?

Tags: ios

I have a project where all views are meant to be in portrait only, except one which is only landscape and no auto-rotation.
I set supported orientations to portrait and landscape in project settings. Then I set these functions for each view controller:

```
- (UIInterfaceOrientation)preferredInterfaceOrientationForPresentation {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationLandscapeLeft; // or Right of course
}

- (UIInterfaceOrientationMask)supportedInterfaceOrientations {
    return UIInterfaceOrientationMaskLandscape;
}

-(BOOL)shouldAutorotate
{
    return NO;
}
```

but it does not work. The simulator allows all views to rotate and seems to ignore the settings altogether.
Am I doing something wrong, or is it a bug in the simulator?

Comment: Is this view controller inside a container view controller?

Answer (score 1):

Most likely the issue is that you've defined the permitted orientations in info.plist which overrides anything specified in code.

Thus you probably need to remove the entries from info.plist.

Comment: I deleted the info.plist entries and I still get the same problem. Also, I tried putting the supportedInterfaceOrientations method in the UINavController, but still no joy.

Answer (score 0):

I finally had to use a bit of a hack to get it working:
I put this line in viewDidLoad:
self.view.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI/2);
everything works fine now